# Commutative combination of elements of two lists

Tags: python

Just a style question: Is there a build-in method to get the combinations under the assertion of commutative property and excluding elements paired with itself?

```
a = ["1", "2", "3"]
b = ["1", "2", "3"]
seen = []
combinations = []

for v1 in a:
    for v2 in b:
        if v1 != v2:
            if (v2, v1) not in seen:
                combinations.append((v1, v2))
                seen.append((v1, v2))

>> [('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '3')]
```

Doesn't seem very Python. I know of itertools.product which is the Cartesian product. I could convert it to a set which would exclude the identity-pairings but it's still the non-commutative product.

Comment: If you had `a = [1,2,3]; b = [4,5,6]`, is `(5,6)` one of the outputs or not?  Can you draw from the same list twice?  (The above code says no.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations), if both lists are the same like here.
Or in the general case [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), followed by some filtering:

```
In [7]: a = ["1", "2", "3"]
   ...: b = ["a", "b", "c"]

In [8]: list(filter(lambda t: t[0] < t[1], product(a,b)))
Out[8]: 
[('1', 'a'),
 ('1', 'b'),
 ('1', 'c'),
 ('2', 'a'),
 ('2', 'b'),
 ('2', 'c'),
 ('3', 'a'),
 ('3', 'b'),
 ('3', 'c')]
```

Also, I think the term *combination* already means that the order of elements in the result doesn't matter.

---

Ok, Theodros is right. For compensation, here's a version which should work on a any list of lists:

```
l = [['1','2','3'], ['a','b'], ['x','y']] 

set(tuple(sorted(p)) for p in product(*l) if len(set(p)) > 1)
```

gives (appropriately sorted)

```
set([('1', 'a', 'x'),
     ('3', 'a', 'y'),
     ('2', 'b', 'y'),
     ('2', 'a', 'y'),
     ('1', 'a', 'y'),
     ('1', 'b', 'y'),
     ('2', 'a', 'x'),
     ('3', 'b', 'y'),
     ('1', 'b', 'x'),
     ('2', 'b', 'x'),
     ('3', 'a', 'x'),
     ('3', 'b', 'x')])
```

And it also works on the previous counterexample `l = [[1,2,3], [1,3,4,5]]`:

```
set([(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 5), (3, 4), (2, 4), (3, 5)])
```

Comment: @TheodrosZelleke Right. I've updated my answer. Edit: ok, there's still a bug... not my day today.

Comment: @phg: your current version can return too-small tuples (e.g. `l = [['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2', '3']]`).  I think `len(s) > 1` needs to be something like `len(s) == len(l)` or something.

Comment: I think that's what I corrected in my last edit. It now gives `[['1', '1', '2'],
 ['1', '1', '3'],
 ['1', '2', '2'],
 ['1', '2', '3'],
 ['1', '3', '3'],
 ['2', '2', '3'],
 ['2', '3', '3']]` for that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `a` and `b` are identical.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = ["1", "2", "3"]
>>> list(itertools.combinations(a,2))
[('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '3')]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work if you do not care that the ordering in the resulting tuples does not map to the input lists (you do not care whether `(1,2)` or `(2,1)`). Here you'll get the combination with the smaller element first:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,3,4,5]

set([(min(x,y), max(x,y)) for x in a for y in b if x != y])
```

gives

```
set([(1, 2),
     (1, 3),
     (1, 4),
     (1, 5),
     (2, 3),
     (2, 5),
     (3, 4),
     (2, 4),
     (3, 5)])
```

With strings

```
a = '1 2 3'.split()
b = '1 3 4 5'.split()
```

you get

```
set([('2', '3'),
     ('3', '5'),
     ('1', '4'),
     ('3', '4'),
     ('1', '5'),
     ('1', '2'),
     ('2', '5'),
     ('1', '3'),
     ('2', '4')])
```

The apparent difference in the ordering comes from the different hashes for the strings and the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the most self-explanatory way to do it so I wouldn't recommend it but I'll include it for completeness.

Uses the fact that the commutative pairs are the upper and lower triangles of the matrix produced by the product of both arrays.

The numpy function [`np.tril_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html) returns a tuple containing the indices for only the lower-triangle of an array.

1. Getting all products excluding commutative pairs (as you want) but including elements paired with itself (not what you want):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> n_vars = len(a)
>>> assert len(b) == n_vars  # Only works if len(a) == len(b)
>>> [(a[i], b[j]) for i, j in zip(*np.tril_indices(n_vars))]
[('1', '1'), ('2', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '1'), ('3', '2'), ('3', '3')]
```

2. Excluding the elements paired with themselves (what you want):

```
>>> [(a[i], b[j]) for i, j in zip(*np.tril_indices(n_vars, k=-1))]
[('2', '1'), ('3', '1'), ('3', '2')]
```

The `k` argument in `np.tril_indices` is an offset parameter so `k=-1` means it doesn't include the diagonal terms.

Since it's a numpy function it's probably very fast.

3. If you convert `a` and `b` to numpy arrays you can also do this:

```
>>> a = np.array(a)
>>> b = np.array(b)
>>> ind = np.tril_indices(n_vars, k=-1)
>>> list(zip(a[ind[0]], b[ind[1]]))
[('2', '1'), ('3', '1'), ('3', '2')]
>>> np.stack([a[ind[0]], b[ind[1]]]).T
array([['2', '1'],
       ['3', '1'],
       ['3', '2']], dtype='<U1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest and most explicit (i.e. self-explanatory) solution is this I think:

```
>>> for i in range(len(a)): 
...     for j in range(i+1, len(b)): 
...         print(a[i], a[j]) 
... 
1 2
1 3
2 3
```

Unless you're doing something very fast in the inner loop, the inefficiency of the python for loops will hardly be a bottleneck.

Or, this:

```
>>> [(a[i], b[j]) for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(i+1, len(b))]
[('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '3')]
```

Answer (score -2):

you mean this?

```
a = ["1", "2", "3"]
b = ["1", "2", "3"]
print [(x,y) for x in a for y in b]
```

output:

```
[('1', '1'), ('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('2', '3'), ('3', '1'), ('3', '2'), ('3', '3')]
```

Comment: This includes dupes which the OP does not want `('1','2')` : `('2','1')`. Also, that can be reproduced with itertools: `[i for i in list(itertools.product(a,b)) if i[0] != i[1]]`

Comment: @Haidro . .ok now see.. the accepted answer. . just same as mine but without `x!=y`

Comment: The accepted answer isn't like yours at all.  It gives `[('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '3')]` on the OP's case; yours gives `[('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('2', '1'), ('2', '3'), ('3', '1'), ('3', '2')]`.

Comment: @DSM: i gave answer just 12 min after the que posted..same. . then removed it.  then posted it again.. with `x!=y`..

Comment: @namit: your original answer gave the full Cartesian product, which was even farther away from what the OP wanted.